What should be the default values for API Url and Portal Url in VS extension settings?
It looks like I messed up with the Codeium VS extension settings and now those API Url and Portal Url are empty strings. Uninstalling and reinstalling the extension doesn't reset the settings and I cannot find anywhere what those values should be. Could somebody post the default values for those properties?
It is my best guess that the problem are those properties. This is how it shows up, when I click on sign in, it opens an explorer window. I mean Windows File Explorer window not an internet explorer, so obviously I cannot sign in. Specifying the key doesn't help as well. Nevertheless, Codeium extension for VSCode works fine. The problem persists only on VS.
